# How do I turn off the screen saver using the command line?

Tags: command-line, 12.04, screensaver

I would like to turn off the screen saver from command line, which used to work with

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type=bool false
```

in natty & oneiric
for precise this does not work.

Any ideas?

I know where I can do [that in the gui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67355/how-do-i-completely-turn-off-screensaver-and-power-management), I'd need the setting for an automatic installation script, that also changes some default settings.

Comment: +1 this only worked in my case: `killall gnome-screensaver ; xset dpms force on`

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/921732/50254 Basically `systemd-inhibit sleep 2h`.

Answer (score 12):

these settings will help

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 3600
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

recheck with dconf-editor

when using the gui, these properties will also change in dconf-editor.

Comment: Interesting fact: If you do a `gsettings list-recursively > old.settings`, disable the screensaver via GUI and do a `gsettings list-recursively > new.settings`, the `diff` between both setting files is empty.

Comment: This still works for `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`. I'm somewhat surprised.

Answer (score 2):

```
killall gnome-screensaver ; xset dpms force on
```

Comment: this does not solve my problem, because the setting is not stored and the screenserver is back after a reboot.

Comment: +1 - This worked for me. all the rest in the planet mentioned did not worked except this

Answer (score 1):

According to [`gsettings`](https://github.com/GNOME/gsettings-desktop-schemas/blob/36a45a9587b4cbef3672fdbe49e84e11291f11c1/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.gschema.xml.in#L11), this should do the trick:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

Comment: This one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 3600` (delay in seconds) does seem to work for me when reset to `4000`. Helps when watching an hours telly on iplayer.

The dconf setting is buried under `org/desktop/applications/screensaver`.

I think the GUI could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to employ this command for all users, but after that it will be run and set upon each login. I can't put it in a code box because there are quoted returns in the command that the code box sees as an end. But will be read quite differently by BASH. Copy and paste the following in a terminal and press enter. Do this for each user. It could be incorporates into an install script as well but you will need someone more experienced with making a script run for each user. Copy and paste the whole thing, from echo to the last autostart blank lines and all, one big copy and paste.

```
echo '#!/bin/bash 

sleep 15 

xset s 0 0 

xset s off 

exit 0' > screensave_off.sh ; chmod +x screensave_off.sh ; echo '[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Exec= sh ~/screensave_off.sh

Hidden=false

NoDisplay=false

X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true

Name=Screen-Saver-Off

Comment=to turn off the Xserver power save' > Screen-Saver-Off.desktop ; chmod +x Screen-Saver-Off.desktop ; mv Screen-Saver-Off.desktop ~/.config/autostart
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what did it for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
killall gnome-screensaver
```

And when I want enable it again

```
gnome-screensaver &
```

This is only a temporary solution but if you're looking for it then that's fine.