# Screen Resolution set too high

Tags: 12.04, display, resolution

I have just upgraded from Natty to Precise.  The LCD monitor is connected through a Belkin KVM switch.  When Ubuntu boots, everything is fine and the monitor comes up at it's max resolution 1280x1024.  When I switch away using the KVM and then come back some time later, the monitor reports that the resolution is too high and presents only a blanked screen.  xrandr shows that the video adapter is capable of 1600x1600, but the display device is not.  I think that when the screen blanks while the KVM is switched to another session and then is restored, it is trying to go to 1600x1600 and hence is not supported.  The only way for me to recover is to hard reboot.  I have not been able to find any way to configure the system so it will NEVER try to use a resolution higher than 1280x1024.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67355/how-do-i-completely-turn-off-screensaver-and-power-management) thread - I had the same similar issue for my 12.04 installation except the resolution was being set too low. Turning off the screen saver fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

**Ctrl+Alt+'-'** - decrease resolution
**Ctrl+Alt+'+'** - increase resolution

Answer (score 0):

if you install ubuntu on oracle vitual box, following the below steps.
open the vitual box -> go to new ->press next button ->give OS name (select linux)->give RAM size and then press next ->use the existing VDI(previously created .vdi) give the vdi of which you cant set the resolution and then click on OK.Now start the vitual box , now you can see the desire resolution on your PC or laptop.

Comment: This would require an inordinate amount of effort to implement and doesn't offer a solution to the question. Running a system in a virtual environment simply to obtain the correct screen resolution is nonsense.