# How to totaly remove blank screen screensaver?

Tags: screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I completely turn off screensaver and power-management?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67355/how-do-i-completely-turn-off-screensaver-and-power-management)

I have no screensaver installed but when I watch movies after a while blank screen comes and I have to get up every time and move mouse to continue watching the movie. It really pisses me off.
I found this command "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false" which allegedly disables blank screen... I put that command in once, and blank screen keeps doing its crap. I did it again, blank screen still works on its own and would not stop. Did it trice, and nothing.
Please someone help me with this, I'm freaking out when trying to watch a decent movie.

I'd have to mention that I once had "xscreensaver" installed but I removed it after awhile.  Don't know if it has something to do with blank screen still work, maybe some else would know.
PLEASE HELP !