# Cannot access Ubuntu 13.04 virtualbox guest in full screen mode after sleep

Tags: virtualbox, freeze, sleep, fullscreen

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 as a guest in Virtualbox 4.2.14, on a Windows 8 host. When the Ubuntu goes to sleep while in full screen  mode, I cannot wake it up. The screen does not respond to input at all. I first have to "Host + F" to get it into normal more before I can type in the password to enter. This is really annoying. Has anyone else experienced this and know how to resolve it? It happens in both 32 and 64 bit versions

Comment: Yeah, that's why I disable useless screensavers in a guest first thing after install to let the host do the power-saving. See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/67355/how-do-i-completely-turn-off-screensaver-and-power-management

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the screen saver other power management features (turn off screen, sleep/suspend, etc.) is the only thing I have found that works. Not really a fix but it will keep the guest OS from locking up.