# Gnome Desktop: Disabling power options

Tags: gnome, shutdown, gnome-power-manager

How do you disable the power management options from appearing under Gnome 3 desktop environment (not unity)?

#### Background

I use my ubuntu box as both a server for various development tools (including services used when not directly logged in) and a display server.  The display server is used by several family members under different logins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with gnome-tweak-tool!

Comment: it would be better if you can describe exactly how to do this - how do you install gnome-tweak-tool?  Where in gnome-tweak-tool is the option.  Do you need to reboot/logout login for this to take effect?  Screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

To install gnome-tweak-tool:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type: sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

To configure it:

1. Open terminal
2. Type gnome-tweak-tool
3. Select "Shell" and there you have 2 power option

Also:

1. Open System Settings (Application->System Tools->Preferences->System Settings)
2. Select Power

Another option is to use dconf-editor, see the first answer from [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67355/how-do-i-completely-turn-off-screensaver-and-power-management)

Comment: Hello 23ars, thank you for the suggestions.  With version 3.10.4 of gnome-tweak-tool on my system there is no 'Shell' element within the tweaks, either as a menu item on the left or within the search results.

There is also no 'Application' menu entry within the session.  Reviewing the system settings does not show any method to disable the power management features of the menus under Gnome 3.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't know...