# Disable Screen Savers on a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualization, remote-desktop, screensaver

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 machine running on a Hyper-V server.  A while back, I downloaded and installed XRDP so that we could enable RDP connectivity (more as an experiment than anything else).
Recently I noticed that some screensaver software (fiberlamp, etc.) was running and consuming CPU unnecessarily.  We rarely actually use the RDP connection, so this isn't happening with a logged-in user.  And as it's a virtual machine, there's no real screen to "save".
Is there an easy way to tell Ubuntu to never run screensavers?  Pretty much all the solutions I've been able to find are for logged-in users who had trouble with screensavers running when videos played, etc.  I just want to disable the little critters totally.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/67355/how-do-i-completely-turn-off-screensaver-and-power-management

Answer (score 2):

Just uninstall whatever package provides the screensaver. E.g. for `xscreensaver`:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge xscreensaver*
```

Or `gnome-screensaver`:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge gnome-screensaver*
```

Or `cinnamon-screensaver`:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge cinnamon-screensaver*
```

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have worked, with one edit.  I had to use apt-get instead of apt.

Comment: You're welcome.  I forgot that 14.04 uses `apt-get` only, as 16.04+ support `apt`, which has a nice progress indicator and some other differences.