# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS doesn't turnoff but screen turns black after login

Tags: 16.04, laptop, screen

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed for 2-3years. But recently my laptop suddenly, in middle of my work, goes dim to 0%. Even after restarting couple of times, the screen goes dim without even showing login screen

[image showing power statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmrQj.png)

[image showing power settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snjIO.png)

Comment: Please make sure is it dim screen or black window of death and edit question accordingly.

Comment: Please also add detail of graphics and operation you did before this problem occur.

Comment: no it is not black window of death. I can see few of my windows opened with keen observation after my screen turns dim to 0%

Comment: Does this happen only when plugged in, or only on battery, or both?  Laptop batteries can wear out and behave in unpredictable ways, like reporting extremely low battery, causing your screen to dim.  Have you gone through **all** your settings, including settings for your screen/screensaver to make sure that all screen dimming is turned off? See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/67355/how-do-i-completely-turn-off-screensaver-and-power-management

Comment: my laptop does work only on AC. I have to use battery to power it up. I've already unchecked "Dim screen to save power" checkbox. Yet the problem persists. It would be helpful if someone could help stop the light from dimming by itself as laptop functions alright